# Does IDistanceOP.EucDistanceFull require a projected coordinate system?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, coordinate-system, distance

I have designed an implementation of ArcObjects' IDistanceOP.EucDistanceFull. It takes its input as a feature class and converts it to a GeoDataset with which EucDistanceFull can work with. It works fine with feature classes in projected coordinate systems, but doesn't execute property on feature classes with unknown or geographic coordinate systems (It will output a blank or black raster).

What could be the issue here? I don't see anywhere in the library documentation that states that EucDistanceFull requires projected coordinate systems.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have found no documentation to the effect that a Projected Coordinate System is required it is perhaps unsurprising that a Geographic Coordinate System is unsupported because the length of a degree varies depending on the latitude.

I suspect that a documentation enhancement is the most that is likely to happen with this but I encourage you to report it to your local Esri support.